# Creating a pivot/summary view using SQL Case Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am attempting to write a SQL statement using CASE in order to make my own pivot/summary view.  [This spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwbH0.png) shows the table that I'm working with (this is a picture of Excel, but I had to replicate false data for security purposes).   I would like to learn how to write a SQL statement that would show the distinct Item number, and the total QTY_SOLD for each year (2012, 2013, 2014).  So essentially, I would have 5 columns:

ITEM, QTY_SOLD, CY2012, CY2013, CY2014

I've tried writing things similar to this:

```
 select distinct ITEM,

case when to_char(Date,'YYYY') = '2012' then sum(QTY_SOLD)

end CY2012,

case when to_char(Date,'YYYY') = '2013' then sum(QTY_SOLD)

end CY2013,

case when to_char(Date,'YYYY') = '2014' then sum(QTY_SOLD)

end CY2014

from ITEMS_SOLD

group by ITEM, to_char(DATE,'YYYY')
```

but I can't seem to get it work properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You were close -- you need to use conditional aggregation:

```
select ITEM,
    sum(case when to_char(Date,'YYYY') = '2012' then QTY_SOLD end) CY2012,
    sum(case when to_char(Date,'YYYY') = '2013' then QTY_SOLD end) CY2013,
    sum(case when to_char(Date,'YYYY') = '2014' then QTY_SOLD end) CY2014
from ITEMS_SOLD
group by ITEM
```

Comment: That's works beautifully!  Thank you so much for your help.  I tried a similar thing earlier except in my grouping clause I did this:

    group by ITEM, TO_CHAR(DATE,'YYYY')

and it kept giving me null values.  But this works perfect.